# C++ - basic function question

Tags: c++, function, call

*Is there any way to make a function call only once?*

Suppose I have some class

```
struct A {

   void MainRoutine(Params) {
      // Want to call other routine only once
   }

   void OtherRoutine(Params) {
      // Do something that should be done only once and
      // what depends on the params
   }
};
```

I want to call `OtherRoutine` only once in `MainRoutine` (I assume that `MainRoutine` is going to be called `N` times. I can't call `OtherRoutine` from the constructor, because it accepts `Params` which may not be available at the time when object is being constructed.

Basically I want to do something like

```
static bool called = false;
if (!called) {
   OtherRoutine(Params);
   called = true;
}
```

*but I hope there is a more "beautiful" way of doing this... **(which could be written in one line)***

Maybe something using `boost::function` or some part of `boost` that I don't know about? :)

Thank you

Comment: One line? Try `static const bool dummy = (OtherRoutine(params), true);` instead. ;)

Comment: @Georg Well, I was actually thinking of some *OBVIOUS* line, but this is also cool)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Boost Thread's [one-time initialization mechanism](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.once)

Answer (score 2):

You can also put the call-only-once logic, which you already outlined, inside `OtherRoutine`, causing it to return early if it has already been executed before.

Logically, its pretty much the same.  Stylistically, it might be nicer.

Comment: And doesn't the standard library / boost have something like `call_function_once` routine? I thought this may be somewhat useful... Anyway, your answer is nice

Answer (score 2):

You were definitely on the right track already. You should put your static 'called' variable inside your struct... ahem: you should make it a class instead, make it private, and make sure the state of the static variable is queried inside of OtherRoutine. **You should not make it more complicated than it needs to be**. Using boost, or anything else for so simple a mechanism is just overkill.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this with boost::function and bind. Assuming you want OtherRoutine only to be called once per object,

```
struct A {
    A() {
        Routine = boost::bind(&A::OtherRoutine, this); 
    }

    boost::function<void()> Routine;

private:
    void MainRoutine() {
        // Do stuff that should occur on every call
    }

    void OtherRoutine() {
        Routine = boost::bind(&A::MainRoutine, this);
        // Do stuff that should only occur once
        MainRoutine();
    }
};

A foo;
foo.Routine(); // OtherRoutine is called
foo.Routine(); // Now all subsequent calls will go to MainRoutine
foo.Routine();
```

I would suggest doing what the other people have said, though. While this may look 'cleaner,' it's overly complicated when compared to the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Another way that verges on "cute" would be to have a static object and call your function from within its constructor.  Something like...

```
   struct OneShotOtherRoutine
   {
      OneShotOtherRoutine(A a, Params params)
      {
         a.OtherRoutine(params);
      }
   };

   struct A
   {
      friend struct OneShotOtherRoutine;
      public:
         void MainRoutine(Params params)
         {
              static OneShotOtherRoutine(params);
              // Main Routine code
         }
      private:
         void OtherRoutine(Params params)
         {
           // Other routine code
         }
  };
```

You'd have to split things up so that each implementation could see the other struct's declaration, but this could do what you want, assuming it's acceptable that `OtherRoutine` gets called when statics are initialized.